# store value from array result to variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have following controller,

```
class mycontroller extends CI_Controller
{
   public function getvalue() {
        $q= $this->db->select(array('value'))
                          ->from('settting')
                          ->get();
         $data['data']= $q->result();
             $this->load->view('myview',$data); 
    }

}
```

In my view:

print_r($data);

Gives output like this

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [value] => wwwwwwwwwwww ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [value] => 5454546 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [value] => 6868 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [value] => 9898 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [value] => 7878 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [value] => 212 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [value] => 87878 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [value] => 8989 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [value] => 212 ) )
```

I am trying to store each single value in variable

when i use ,

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
   echo $row->value;
}
```

its give me all value but i need to save each value in variable.

how can i do this,
like this,

```
$var1='wwwwwwwwwwww'; // [0 ] array value  
$var2='5454546';      // [1]  array value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

better save it to another array

```
$my_values = array();
foreach($data as $row)
{
   $my_values[] = $row->value;
}
```

now you have :

```
echo $my_values[0]; // wwwwwwwwwwww
echo $my_values[1]; // 5454546
```

Answer (score 4):

When you print a query variable,

```
print_r($query);
```

you would get following result

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
               [Id] => 14 
               [username] => john 
               [password] => e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e 
               [email] => john@gmail.com 
               [key] => 7f55570435fd15393f27eaac659b078a 
               [is_active] => 1 
               [gender] => Man 
               [countryid] => 1 
               [stateid] => 4 
               [cityid] => 4 
               [age] => 31 
       ) )
```

So if you want to get the value of a single element from this array, you can write the following code -

```
echo $query[0]->username;
```

then you get the following value

```
john
```

I hope this solves your problems. I'm sure that you might have already found the answer. but i got the same problem, so i thought it might help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

You can  try like this

```
class mycontroller extends CI_Controller
{
   public function getvalue() {
        $q = $this->db->select(array('value'))
                  ->from('settting')
                  ->get()
                  ->result_array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($q as $val)
        {
            ${'var' . ++$i} = $val['value']; // Here we put each value in new variable, with variable name var1, var2, ...
        }
        echo $var1;
        echo $var2;
        $this->load->view('myview',$data); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You strategy is totally wrong. You are calling a db call from a controller which breaks MVC rule. Create a model for this.

```
Class Value Extends CI_Model{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function getValue(){
return $this->db
            ->select(array('value'))
            ->from('settting')
            ->get();
            ->result();

}
```

And now call it from controller

```
class mycontroller extends CI_Controller
{
   $this->load->model('value');
   public function getvalue() {

        $data['value']= $this->value->getValue();   
        $this->load->view('myview',$data); 
    }
}
```

And now in the view

```
foreach($value as $row)
{
    echo $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look array is containing  "stdClass Object" object. So you need to convert object into array. So convert using,

```
$data= $q->result();
$data['data']=$data->result_array();  or $data->row_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop through the result with some tempoarary variable to construct variable. But i don't know whats the use of storing the array values in seperate variable :-)

```
$i = 0;
 foreach($data as $row)
{
  $var_.$i = $row->value;
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: :because value comes from single colum "value"  not from row and i want to show this value in textbox on form open.